# Can I call a Stored Procedure in a FROM clause - MYSQL, If not what are the options?

Tags: mysql

I've got a Stored Procedure that I need to call into a select statement to add additional filtering.

I've tried creating a temp table and inserting the data into there, but I've not been able to get it working.

```
CREATE temporary table reporting.test
(
  bookid varchar(60), 
  title varchar(80), 
  age int, 
  author varchar(60), 
  description text
)


INSERT INTO reporting.test (  bookid , title , age , author , description )
SELECT bookid , title , age , author , description from 
  (
  call  `reporting`.`books`('00ab16ae-7402-441d-b9a2-45a3f4793adf', 'Booktitle', 'Author')
  )
```

I've seen examples of below; but I can't seem to get that working either.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
call  `reporting`.`books`('00ab16ae-7402-441d-b9a2-45a3f4793adf', 'Booktitle', 'Author')
) AS reporting.test
```

My stored procedure takes 3 parameters and it works just as a call statement.
Will I need to use dynamic SQL.

When trying to execute the statements, I receive the following error:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'call  `reporting`.`books`('00ab16ae-7402-441d-b9'
> at line 77

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Even in SQL Server (which you said you used) you wouldn't be able to call a procedure in the`FROM`/`SELECT`.

Comment: The answer to your question will be different depending on the actual DBMS you are using. To insert the results of a Microsoft SQL Server stored procedure into a table, `INSERT INTO reporting.test ( bookid , title , age , author , description ) EXECUTE reporting.books '00ab16ae-7402-441d-b9a2-45a3f4793adf', 'Booktitle', 'Author';`. The stored proc result set must match the specified columns.

Comment: @Dan Guzman error message 1064 is a mysql error

Comment: You cannot call a procedure in this way - can you post procedure code please.

Comment: @P.Salmon, I know the error is MySQL but the original question called out both MySQL and MSSQL. Larnu since removed the MSSQL reference. It is unclear of the Mary_xoxo is needing a solution for both DBMS prooducts, which will differ.

Comment: Sorry to be unclear, it is MYSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot call a procedure in a subquery. You can only use SELECT in a subquery.

The reason is that procedures return multi-results. The results can be dissimilar (i.e. different columns in number and data type).

Example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p()
BEGIN
  SELECT id, txt, created_at FROM table1;

  SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) FROM table2;
END
```

There's no way a subquery could return multiple results.

So your only option to call a procedure is to use CALL as a top-level statement.

If you need to filter the rows of the results, then you need to write a loop to process the rows. This is typically done in application code. You can't do it in a stored procedure, because the DECLARE CURSOR only works for SELECT statements, not CALL statements (again because procedures return multi-results).

Another option is to call a stored function instead of a stored procedure. Stored functions can accept arguments, and you can call it with SELECT in a subquery, but a stored function only return a single scalar value, not multiple columns, multiple rows, or multiple results.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT `reporting`.`myfunction`(...) AS f
) AS reporting.test
```